# With Cypress, how to get the response body of an api call triggered by a non-request event

Tags: cypress

I am testing my login page with cypress. The call to my api `/api/auth/login` is triggered automatically when the input field of the password reaches 4 characters. So in my cypress spec file, the command `cy.get("password-input").type("1234")` is enough to trigger the api call. How can I get the response body of that api call? I would like to get the token my api sends back.

In classic api calls with the `cy.request` command I can easily handle the response body, but I couldn't find how to access the response body when the api request is triggered by another event like here with the `type` event.

Currently, I have a workaround because my website stores the response.body.token in the localStorage, so I access the token with `window` and after a `wait`:

[image: cypress test run]

```
it("should get token", () => {
  cy.visit("/login")
  cy.get("[data-cy="login-input"]).type("myLogin")
  cy.get("[data-cy="password-input"]).type("0001")
  cy.wait(5000)
  cy.window().then(window => {
    cy.log(window.localStorage.getItem("myToken"))
  })
})
```

But this feels gross... Could you give me the  proper way to access the response body of the api call triggered by the `type` event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cy.intercept()`, aliasing, and `cy.wait()`:

```js
it("should get token", () => {
  cy
    .intercept('/api/auth/login')
    .as('token');
  cy
    .visit("/login");
  cy
    .get('[data-cy="login-input"]')
    .type("myLogin");
  cy
    .get('[data-cy="password-input"]')
    .type("0001");
  cy
    .wait('@token')
    .then(intercept => {
      // you can now access the request body, response body, status, ...
    });
});
```

Useful reading:

- https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept
- https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Aliasing-individual-requests
- https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait
- https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait#Alias

Comment: Brillan ! Thanks ! I actually also tried with intercept but I realized with your post I didn't use it as it was intended... Thanks also for the links....